# how to run a simple c program in openvms?

Tags: compilation, openvms

How to compile and link the sample c program in openVMS ?Can any one please explain the process and how can debugging process is don in OpenVMS?

Comment: Have you got a C compiler installed, to start with? If so, `help` should be available, e.g.: http://fafner.dyndns.org/cgi-bin/conan.com?key=CC

Answer (score 7):

Well, in OpenVMS to create a source file you should use

```
edit/edt namefile.c
```

Then type

```
c
```

or

```
change
```

is the same.
You'll have the editor ready to work.
When you have finished to write your code and type

```
ctrl Z
```

Now you can type another command, to save type

```
ex
```

or

```
exit
```

if you don't want to save type

```
quit
```

When you are again in your directory to compile the file type

```
cc namefile.c
```

then do the linking

```
link namefile.obj
```

and at least if you haven't any error

```
run namefile.exe
```

I hope it is usefull! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic.
Please start with the manuals and /or google

http://h71000.www7.hp.com/commercial/c/docs/5492profile.html
"Chapter 1 shows how to create, compile, link, and run a HP C program."
"C.1 OpenVMS Debugger"
http://h71000.www7.hp.com/commercial/c/docs/5492profile_036.html#index_x_1416
(pdf available)

If you have specific issues, please do not hesitate to ask.
Regards,
Hein